# Widget refresh from inside application

Tags: android, listview, widget, sharedpreferences, android-widget

Good Day! I want to add text from inside application to widget, i have a main activity and it has list view and lots of text contents and it has a button to add the text to widget via shared preference, it's works fine when i close the widget and recreate it only, otherwise it's not automatically refresh.if anyone know; how to solve this please help me. here i attached the widget code below.

```
    public class WidgetMaster extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    Intent intentHome = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentHome = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentHome, 0);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_master);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wid_home, pendingIntentHome);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferencestoWi = context.getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(R.string.addTextToWidgetPref), MODE_PRIVATE);
    String forWidget = sharedPreferencestoWi.getString("textToWidget", "");
    String dum = "add from reading";
    if(forWidget.equals("")){
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.dum_appwidget_text, dum);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    } else {
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, forWidget);
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.appwidget_text, 0);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }

}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How do you update the widget from mainActivity?

In the widget configuration file you can specify a fixed update interval. The smallest update interval is 1800000 milliseconds (30 minutes).

But its better to update widget programmatically, to do this You should send a broadCast to update widget and use a
method like alarmManager or Handler for a repeating task 
 for example you can use the following broadCast to update widget form mainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WidgetMaster.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);                   

int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication())
                      .getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(),WidgetMaster.class));
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```